# Searching using LIKE not returning expected result

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am searching on MySQL database using PHP and `LIKE` method, everything works great except when I type some characters like `#`, `_`, `&` it returns all rows even that there is not any row that has any of this character on it.

Other characters like `/`, `"`, `'` works great and shows just the rows that has those characters.

The follow code is the code I use to get those results.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$value%'")
```

Comment: `$value = addcslashes($value,'_%);`, [and some reading on LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). Also, don't use the deprecated `mysql` extension anymore, use `mysqli` or `PDO`, and use prepared statements if you can.

Comment: _ is the placeholder for a single char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a special character, representing any single character, in the same way that `%` represents any sequence of multiple characters

`\` is an escape character, used if you want to search for a literal percent character `\%`, underscore `\_` or slash `\\` (unless `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` mode is enabled)

**EDIT**

See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for details

Comment: So if I use regex and replace all this characters like _ with \_ and so on... that is the solution? What about # and & as far as I know they are not special characters here at LIKE

Comment: I can't answer about `#` or `&`, I've listed the documented special characters for MySQL, and added the link to that documentation

Comment: You can only use \\ at the end of a pattern-string, otherwise, you should use \\\\. [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/657c4/1)

Comment: I have escaped successfully _(underline) but still having problems with symbols like +, #, &. I am using jQuery and Get method to send the search value to PHP script, I am seeing now that this symbols are not going at PHP at all, maybe Javascript escapes them and does not send to PHP?

Comment: In that case, make sure that you urlencode the value before using jQuery to send it to the server: but a bit of debug in our PHP script will tell you what value is being received by the server

Comment: Thanks a lot, urlencode fixed everything, it seems like javascript had those characters as special and did not send at PHP at all.

Answer (score -4):

You may try using `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: I have used it for $value variable. The problem still exists.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated - read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: While one _should_ indeed escape ones variables for the deprecated mysql extension, this won't help in a LIKE scenario.